# Why do i get the wrong output in my math equation

Tags: python, math

I just started out classes on python. For homework, the professor had us write a function that has an output as follows `a = ((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3)**(1/n)` i wrote the code like this `a = ((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3) ** 1/n` i want to understand why do i get a different output don't they put calculate it to the power of `1/n`?

Comment: `**` has higher precedence than `/`.

Comment: Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally

Comment: It's a simple maths as Fred highlighted. Let's consider as `((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3)` as `x`. In the first equation it becomes `x/3 ** (1/n)` [The equation `x/3` raised to the whole power of `1/n`] whereas the second equation becomes `(x/3) ** 1/3` [`x/3` raised to power 1 and then divide by 3 which is nothing but `(x/3)/3 = x/9`]

Comment: This is basic math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a = ((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3) ** 1/n` === `a = (((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3) ** 1)/n`
So the value changes than that of expected.

So the expression is `a = ((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3)**(1/n)` is different from `a = ((x**n + y**n + z**n) / 3) ** 1/n`

Comment: So in other words this is a math issue, not programming whatsoever?